# Having Problems Installing Flash Player

Tags: installation, flash

Hey guys when I tried to install the flash player from the terminal I got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 flashplugin-installer : Depends: libnss3-1d but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libnspr4-0d but it is not going to be installe
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, so I could use your help.I also had an error installing it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Check [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/717351/156176) on a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install adobe flash player](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342863/cannot-install-adobe-flash-player)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable “ubuntu-restricted-extras” in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Check out this link http://linuxinternetworks.com/easy-method-to-install-adobe-flash-player-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting that error that I have unmet dependencies.