# Cannot install adobe flash player

Tags: installation, apt, flash, adobe

I can't install Adobe Flash player. I tried terminal, Ubuntu Software Centre, and Synaptic Package Manager, but I got error message:

```
flashplugin-installer:
Depends: libnss3-1d but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libnspr4-0d but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried `apt-get update`, but it's not working. I also tried installing `libnss3-1d` and `libnspr4-0d` but I got an error message.

I also tried using Ubuntu-restricted-extras, but I cannot get Flash installed.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?  64bit or 32bit?

Comment: Can you please run `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`?

Comment: Mitch : 32-bit.
Alaa : that's not working.

Comment: Could you run `apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer libnss3-1d libnspr4-0d`, `apt-cache depends flashplugin-installer libnss3-1d libnspr4-0d` and `sudo apt-get check`, edit your question and add the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just meant as a hint here - you don't need to install flash-player manually for browsers like firefox. Could be easier to get around that with usage of Chrome Browser. Less stress than many adjustments in firefox - which are getting obsolete again after a few newer versions of firefox ...

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions in Alaa's comment did the trick for me, so thx Alaa!

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnspr4=2:4.10.2-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

## Long answer

I tried to do install libnspr4-0d manually, but I got this error:

> libnspr4-0d : Depends: libnspr4 (= 2:4.10.2-1ubuntu1) but
>   2:4.10.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed

I checked libnspr4 and it was already installed, so I had to downgrade it. So the solution is to check every package and install (or reinstall) it using the version needed by `flashplugin-installer`