# Adobe Flash Player fail to install

Tags: software-installation, flash

When I try to install Adobe Flash Player it tells me to check the internet connection when I have internet connection. what to do??

Comment: Which ubuntu version you are using?

Comment: Check this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/342863/cannot-install-adobe-flash-player.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Answer (score 0):

for installing using **software center**: Click on this link:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras

or in a terminal: type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

synaptic: search for the package **ubuntu-restricted-extras** right click the package and select install, and then select mark. after click the apply button and it will all install.

for more ways use this link 
[How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)